# Please make your baby keep track of numbers

Tags: bug, reputation, top-bar

Dear Stack Overflow team,

you have made an awesome baby. However, it's now grown, and I think it's high time it should learn to properly keep track of numbers and stop confusing me with silly mistakes.

[image: 21 vs. 20]

Comment: It's not a silly mistake.  The +1 is probably from an answer you previously downvoted and got deleted (which returned the +1 to you).  Those types of changes do not show up in your rep feed.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/duQXa.png) has something to do with it?

Comment: @psubsee2003: __1)__ Just the other day it pointed out the deleted question. __2)__ Even if it was that way, it's an error. If I have 21 rep, and expand the list to see where I got them, I should be able to see where they came from. At the very least, It should say "-1 (deleted answer)".

Comment: @sbi Well that's what I'm seeing now. I took that screenshot just 2 mins ago.

Comment: @sbi if you want to change how the rep feed works, go for it.  I'm just pointing out that it is not a bug because this is how the system is designed to work.

Comment: @Sam: I reloaded the page and opened that menu again, and it still doesn't show up. So the bug is still there.

Comment: @sam I see it, too

Comment: @sbi Have you tried logging out and then viewing your profile?

Comment: @psubsee2003: I do understand what you are getting at, and I think I agree that this would explain the issue. But you seem to fail to understand that the issue is still a bug. It does not show up in the drop down menu.

Comment: @sbi that's what I'm trying to say, it is by design, so it can't be a bug.

Comment: It must be a feature...

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210139/new-top-bar-cant-math

Comment: @Sam: Again, it might well be that deleted questions show up elsewhere (and it might well be that I misremember and it was there where I believed I saw the deleted question the other day). However, that doesn't change the fact that this `-1` doesn't show up in the dropdown, even though it's indicated on the button that opens it.

Comment: It's by design. Not a bug.  "Just like your profile, we don't show changes due to deleted posts in the achievements dropdown. They are however available in your profile if you opt to see them via the checkbox at the bottom of the reputation tab."

Comment: @Bart: Thanks, so this is a dupe. Since I cannot close it as a dupe of that other site's answer, I'll just delete it.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Then it's a bug by design. A bug nonetheless.

Comment: That's your opinion, but it doesn't make it right

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should have been asked on MSE (where it's already answered: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210139/133368).

Comment: @sbi We clearly disagree about what is a bug.  A bug is a failure of the system to operate as it was designed.  So if it is designed that way and operating as it was intended, then it isn't a bug just because you don't like how it is working.  If you don't like how a feature works, you can certainly proposed a new feature request to modify the behavior.  I might even support the idea because it think the behavior is strange.

Comment: @psubsee2003: There's design bugs.

Answer (score 12):

You had downvoted an answer, which cost you -1 reputation. That answer has now been deleted, and you have been reimbursed the spent reputation.

Yes, it is strange that it doesn't show up in the "Achievements" menu, but this is not a bug. The team considers it "by design". These minor adjustments of reputation are not seen as significant enough to earn a place in the menu.

If you want to see them, you can go to the "Reputation" tab in your profile. Note that, even there, these are hidden by default. You must have the "show removed posts" box checked in order to see them.

Prior discussions on the global Meta:

- [Reputation items in the achievements dropdown don't add up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210139/new-top-bar-cant-math)
- [Deleted downvotes should appear in Achievements dialog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208251/top-bar-reputation-accounting-should-add-up)
- [Inconsistent and confusing rep total in achievements tray after downvoted answer was deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209395/inconsistent-and-confusing-rep-total-in-achievements-tray-after-downvoted-answer)

Comment: Then it is a bug by design.

Comment: I think the term you're looking for is "feature I think is a bad idea".

Comment: See also: [Don't light up the achievements indicator when the only change is removed downvotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210882) and [Topbar tells me about a +1 recovered from a deleted DVed post but detail view doesn't show it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225463) @sbi. I take Shog's answer to the former as a "won't fix".